# Inverter os fatores em apenas 1 barra no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como a ordem dos fatores em apenas 1 barra no ggplot2? Reordenar os dados não funciona mais :(

No caso eu gostaria de inverter a primeira barra, de maneira que o verde ficasse para cima e o vermelho para baixo.

[image: Exemplo]

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- expand.grid(a = letters[1:5], b = letters[1:2])
dados$a <- paste(dados$a)
dados$b <- paste(dados$b)
dados$val <- rnorm(10, 5, 1)
ggplot(aes(x = a, y = val, fill = b), data = dados) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

dados2 <- rbind(tail(dados, -1), head(dados, 1))
ggplot(aes(x = a, y = val, fill = b), data = dados2) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') # Funcionava nas versões anteriores :\
```

Comment: Apenas na primeira barra?

Comment: @Daniel sim, apenas na 1a barra

Comment: Ela provavelmente vai ter que ser um geom_bar separado, que vem de um conjunto de dados separado

Answer (score 5):

Gambiarra, mas funciona:

```
dados2$c <- ifelse(dados2$a == "a", dados2$b, NA)
dados2$d <- ifelse(dados2$a == "a", dados2$val, NA)
dados2$val[dados2$a == "a"] <- NA
ggplot(aes(x = a, y = d, fill = c), data = dados2) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = a, y= val, fill = b), stat= "identity")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gambiarra é o que há